# python salted hashes producing unexpected results using sha1 and md5

Tags: python-3.x, hash, cryptography, md5, sha1

I am trying to write a simple python script to hash a list of passwords and compare the resulting hashes against a list. I know that these 4 hashes match 4 of the listed passwords hashed with sha1 and salted with either md5(1), md5(2), md5(3), md5(4) or md5(5). My code prints 50 unique hashes however none of them match and I can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

```
import hashlib

possibleHashes = ["9537935389a343a4fbd831b621b00661b91a5172", "576b1b134cb89b0f8a6c4dd1698479a1151b0e63", "5d7196b530fdd24b8faaaecbaa6b08a29daa1304", "d6acda01abcfe8afd510b96c1d0a1645ea4c40b8"]
possiblePasswords = ["123456", "123456789", "qwerty", "password", "12345", "qwerty123", "1q2w3e", "12345678", "111111", "1234567890"]
hashesFound = 0

def hashPassword(saltNum, password):
    password = password.encode('utf-8')
    encryptedPassword = hashlib.sha1(hashlib.md5(int.to_bytes(saltNum)).digest() + password).hexdigest()
    return encryptedPassword



i = 0
while (i < len(possiblePasswords)):
    j = 0
    print("I: ", i)
    while (j < 5):
        j += 1
        print("J: ", j, " " + hashPassword(j, possiblePasswords[i]))
        if (hashPassword(j, possiblePasswords[i]) in possibleHashes):
            print(possiblePasswords[i], "\n" + hashPassword(j, possiblePasswords[i]))
                
    i += 1
    if i == 10:
        print("\nHash Matches Found: ", hashesFound, "\n")
        quit()
```

Edit:
I have tried making saltNum a string and encoding it before it's used in the md5 call however it has made no difference.

Comment: *...I know that these 4 hashes match 4 of the listed passwords hashed with sha1 and salted with either md5(1), md5(2), md5(3), md5(4) or md5(5)...*: Obviously this is not correct, otherwise your code should return matches (at least from the line `print(possiblePasswords[i],...`, regarding `print("\nHash...`, `hashesFound` is not incremented).

Comment: @NotARobot It is correct. I have confirmed it via brute forcing using online encryptors which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Then your online encryptor obviously uses a different logic than the implemented one (otherwise it would work). So you would have to describe your online brute forcing in more detail (web site, settings, parameters etc.). Otherwise, the question contains nothing more than a non-working code, which is not sufficient to answer.